# Excel VBA to find out difference between two dates in days. where dates come from different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get date difference in days from two dates using a macro in Excel. Addition on that first date should be from `sheet1`

And another(2nd) date is from `sheet2` and their output(days difference) we have to show in `sheet3` in Excel.

I tried this:

```
 Dim i As Range,j As Range, ifind As Range, y,z, dest As Range, jfind As Range
 On Error Resume Next
 Worksheets("sheet3").Cells.Clear
 With Worksheets("sheet1")
 .UsedRange.Copy Worksheets("sheet3").Range("a1")
 For Each i In Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
 y=i.value
 With Worksheets("sheet1")
 Set ifind = .Cells.Find(what:=y, lookat:=ylWhole)
 For Each j In Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
 z=j.value
 With Worksheets("sheet2")
 Set jfind = .Cells.Find(what:=z, lookat:=zlWhole)
 If ifind and jfind Is Nothing Then GoTo line1
 set datefind="datedif("ifind","jfind","d")" .Copy
 With Worksheets("sheet3")
 End with 'sheet2
 end with 'sheet2
 line1:
 Next
 end with 'sheet1
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: yes, i tried many ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:-

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim currDate As Date
Dim dateOffset As Integer
Dim count1 As Integer
Dim str As String
Dim cuntfinal As Integer
Dim strfinal As String
countfinal = 2
 count1 = 2
 count0 = 2
 strdate = "d" & CStr(count0)
For Each cell In Range(Sheet3.Range(strdate), Sheet3.Range(strdate).End(xlDown))
 strdate = "d" & CStr(count0)
 count0 = count0 + 1
 If cell Is Nothing Then GoTo line10
  startDate = Sheets("Sheet3").Range(strdate)
  str = "h" & CStr(count1)
 For Each cell1 In Range(Sheet3.Range(str), Sheet3.Range(str).End(xlDown))
  count1 = count1 + 1
  GoTo line20
  Next cell1
line20:
 If cell1 Is Nothing Then GoTo line10
currDate = Sheets("Sheet3").Range(str)
If currDate = "12:00:00 AM" Then GoTo line40

dateOffset = DateDiff("d", startDate, currDate)
line30:
strfinal = "j" & CStr(countfinal)
Sheets("Sheet3").Range(strfinal) = dateOffset
countfinal = countfinal + 1
line10:
Next cell
line40:
strfinal = "j" & CStr(countfinal)
Sheets("Sheet3").Range(strfinal) = " "
countfinal = countfinal + 1
 GoTo line10
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean but it could just be this (it depends on where your dates are located in `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. Ive assumed they are descending in column 1):

```
Sub Days()
'Count Number of Dates in "Sheet1"
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
NumberDates = 0
t = 1
Do While Cells(t, 1)
    t = t + 1
Loop
NumberDates = t - 1

'Place Formula for date difference in Sheet3
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(t, 1))
    .Formula = "=DAYS(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1)"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i am not able to undrstand "count number of dates" vala logic. even i tried this code.its giving "run time error" on DO while Cells(t,1) line.   Can you help me.?

Comment: It was only to ensure you didn't plaster the formula all over Sheet3. Maybe you should upload the file to the comment if you can't give a better description of the data you have.

Comment: I think, i alredy wrote my question with description that what exactly i am searching for.Let me know if you can help me.

Comment: Nobody can help you until you improve the question.

Comment: There are three sheets in excel( sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3) i have some data in two sheets(sheet1 and sheet2). Forget about that in sheet1 there is a column with startdate(It containts date) and sheet2 there is a column stopdate(It containts date). I want difference between those two dates in days(like we are calculating age in days from birthdate) and that output(difference in days) i want to show in sheet3 using macro.